# Where can I see the average transaction fee payed in the last 100 blocks?

Tags: transactions, blockchain

Is there a site that shows what's the average transaction fee payed in the last X blocks? Or just raw data about this?

I checked [BlockExplorer](http://blockexplorer.com/) and [Sytes](http://blockexplorer.sytes.net/chain/Bitcoin) and they don't seem to show this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Blockchain.info](http://blockchain.info/) shows the amount of fees [payed each day](http://blockchain.info/charts/transaction-fees).